# Android: Disable new activity animation

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-animation

When i open a new activity, the new activity kind of pops up, is it possible to disable that animation and instead make it so that the new activity instantly just switches places with the old one?

Its hard to explain the effect i'm looking for but i hope you understand what i mean :)

this is the code im using to open the new activity:

```
final ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCall);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(ContacsActivity.this,CallActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Could you reference any video or resource to show what effect do you want to recreate? 
Anyway, to apply your transition, you can use overridePendingTransition(). See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29 for more details

Comment: There is like a "transition" effect as a default when you open a new activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `overridePendingTransition()` right after you call `startActivity()` and provide your own animation to be used in its place.  See the `Activity` documentation for more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html.